# Is it possible to plot this transfer function on MATLAB / GNU Octave?

Tags: filter, control, control-system, transfer-function, matlab

I have to implement a transfer function such that

$$H(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{B(z) - z^{-N} \: C(z)}{A(z)}$$

where \$A(z) = z^2 - 1.9 \: z + 0.98 \$, \$B(z) = z^2\$ and \$C(z) = -0.162126 \: z + 0.139770\$ with \$N = 300\$. I just need to plot the impulse response of \$H(z)\$ given \$A(z)\$, \$B(z)\$ and \$C(z)\$. I have some knowledge of GNU Octave (currently working on it instead of MATLAB), but I don't really know where to start. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Where is \$k\$ in the sum?

Comment: plot what exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, (assuming that the \$N\$ in the sum must be \$k\$) we know that:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\sum_{\text{k}\space=\space0}^\text{n}\frac{\text{B}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{s}^{-\text{k}}\text{C}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{A}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\left(1+\text{n}\right)\text{B}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{A}\left(\text{s}\right)}+\frac{\left(\text{s}-\text{s}^{-\text{n}}\right)\text{C}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\left(1-\text{s}\right)\text{A}\left(\text{s}\right)}\tag1$$

Now, using a impulse response we know that \$\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)=1\$ so the output is given by:

$$\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\underbrace{\frac{\left(1+\text{n}\right)\text{B}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{A}\left(\text{s}\right)}}_{:=\space\mathcal{I}_1\left(\text{s}\right)}+\underbrace{\frac{\left(\text{s}-\text{s}^{-\text{n}}\right)\text{C}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\left(1-\text{s}\right)\text{A}\left(\text{s}\right)}}_{:=\space\mathcal{I}_2\left(\text{s}\right)}\tag2$$

Using the inverse Laplace transform, we can see that (using your values):

$$\text{y}\left(t\right)=\underbrace{\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\mathcal{I}_1\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(t\right)}}_{:=\space\mathscr{I}_1\left(t\right)}+\underbrace{\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\mathcal{I}_2\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(t\right)}}_{:=\space\mathscr{I}_2\left(t\right)}\tag3$$

Where:

- $$\mathscr{I}_1\left(t\right)=\frac{301\exp\left(\frac{19 t}{20}\right)}{310}\cdot\left(165
     \sqrt{31} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{31} t}{20}\right)+589 \cos
     \left(\frac{\sqrt{31} t}{20}\right)\right)\tag4$$
- $$\mathscr{I}_2\left(t\right)=$$
  $$\frac{9 t^{299} \left(-943299 e^t+e^{\frac{19 t}{20}} \left(1424729
     \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{31} t}{20}\right)-264641 \sqrt{31} \sin
     \left(\frac{\sqrt{31} t}{20}\right)\right)-481430\right)}{30380000
     \Gamma (300)}\tag5$$

Comment: This might have been true if it was a continuous-time transfer function, but it's a discrete time. The expansion of the sum works the same, though.

Comment: The questing is asking about plotting not providing the analytical solution.